# Does Ruby OpenSSL lib support RSA OAEP 256

Tags: ruby, openssl, rsa

I can not decrypt encrypted data (RSA OAEP 256) using Ruby OpenSSL. I wonder whether Ruby support this alg?

Answer (score 1):

Until now([Ruby 2.5.1 OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS12.html)), I don't see they include this features.

But, I found this [gem](https://github.com/terashi58/openssl-oaep) which may support.